# Why we can use Node head = null without instantiate the 'head' in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am reading someone's code. It is about getting input numbers and convert those number into a Linked list. The part of the code is like this:

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;
    Node() {
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Firstly We need to create a `head` node to indicate head and we let the `head` be null like this **`Node head = null`**.

My limited experiences of java tell me that `head` is supposed to be a Node type object here. So why we can use `Node head = null` without instantiate the `head`?

I think at least I should create **`Node head = new Node()`**; then we can use **`Node head = null`**;

Anyone can explain it to me?

Comment: Why would you need an object before you can assign `null` to a reference?

Comment: There's no point to that assignment, `null` is the default value for fields of `Object` types.

Comment: Oracle provides useful information and tutorials for classes and objects. It looks likes you should read them, to understand how and why your code works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node head = null;
```

This line states that there are no items in the linked list. This is valid in Java and indicates that although head can contain a `Node` object (or an object of a derived class), it is currently empty.

To add an item to the list, there is likely some code such as:

```
public void addItemToLinkedList(int value) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node();
        head.value = value;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So if there is no first Node (when head equals null) then head is created. Otherwise if head already exists, the else block would execute which would look for the end of the list and add another Node.

Comment: Why head can use the Node as its data type without instantiation?

Comment: It just means that `head` can contain objects of type `Node` (or derived from `Node`), but it can also be empty - the null indicates that it is empty. Think of `head` like a mailbox. It can contain letters, or it can be empty.

Comment: Ok, So if I say Node someone = null; It means someone can contain object of type Node. It does not mean someone is Node object?

Comment: Yes. Not until you say `Node someone = new Node();`  or `Node someone = someoneelse;` where `someoneelse` was an instantiated Node object.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much Jason.

Answer (score 1):

> `head` is supposed to be a Node type object here

This is optional. Java allows `head` to be a `Node` object, or `null`, to indicate that `head` is not referencing any nodes at all.

The value of `null` is special in Java. It is allowed to go wherever an object can go. It indicates that the variable to which you assign `null` is empty. This is perfectly fine, assuming that the rest of your program deals with null checking.

Comment: So if Java allowed head to be a Node object then tail also can be Node object, right? How about the prev and next, are they can be Node type as well? Is there any document I can read about Node object in java? Thank you.

Comment: @Jeffery *"Is there any document I can read about Node object in java"* I don't think so, because `Node` is your own class (so no other page knows it). But I've linked a help page from Oracle about general classes and objects. It might help you as well.